# Display PIL image in PHP script

Tags: php, python, image, curl, python-imaging-library

I have a python script generating PIL image. I need to send this picture to the php script using curl. I found only one way to do that: convert the image to the byte array and return it as text:

```
# image is a PIL object
from PIL import Image
import io, json

image = Image.open('test.png', mode = 'r')
img_io = io.BytesIO()
image.save(img_io, format='PNG')
byte_array = img_io.getvalue()
print(json({'image':byte_array}))
```

Next I decode this byte array and display the image with this php code:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($result, true);
$image = $result['image']
echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64, $image' />"
```

However, I don't know is that OK.

The question is: is there a more correct way to get the PIL image in php with curl?

Answer (score 0):

create route

```
@app.route('/image/', methods=['GET'])
def image():
    return create_image('test.png')
```

create image

```
def create_image(parameter):
    image = Image.open(parameter, mode = 'r')
    img_io = io.BytesIO()
    merge.save(img_io, 'PNG', quality=100)
    img_io.seek(0)
    return send_file(img_io, mimetype='image/png')
```

show your image where you want

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($result, true);
$image = $result['image']
echo "<img src='http://YOUR_FLASK_IP:5000/image/' />"
```